# javafx freezing on rotated display

Tags: raspbian, java

I have a rather weird issue, and have tried so hard to fix. I am running a javafx program on RPI2, the issue comes when i rotate the screen 90 degrees i.e /boot/config.txt display_rotate=1, the app freezes after exactly 1/2 hour. i do not have this issue when screen rotation display_rotate=0. nor do i have this issue when running the app on RPI1 on either rotations. this is regardless of the code in the javafx

I have tried with different javafx versions and have up to date distribution (Rasbian)

please help?

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out. it has to do with screen blanking. but strangely this only happened when the screen is rotated.

all i did is edit set in /etc/kbd/config:

and change 
BLANK_TIME=30

to 
BLANK_TIME=0